# Show $\mathbb{E}(\theta| Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{n}) \to \theta$ a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales

The following is excercise 5.5.2 from Durrett's *Probability Theory and Examples*.

> Let $Z_{1}, Z_{2}, \ldots, Z_{n}$ be i.i.d. with
>   $\mathbb{E}|Z_{i}|<\infty$, let $\theta$ be be an independent random
>   variable with finite mean, and let $Y_{i}=Z_{i} + \theta$. Show that
>   $\mathbb{E}(\theta| Y_{1}, Y_{2}, \ldots, Y_{n}) \to \theta$ a.s.

I have started by using theorem 5.5.7 in Durrett to show that, if $\mathcal{F}_{n} = \sigma(Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{n})$, then we have
$$\mathbb{E}(\theta | Y_{1}, Y_{2}, \ldots, Y_{n}) = \mathbb{E}(\theta | \mathcal{F}_{n}) \to \mathbb{E}(\theta | \mathcal{F}_{\infty})$$
a.s. and in $L^{1}$, where $\mathcal{F}_{\infty} = \sigma\left( \bigcup_{i\geq 1} Y_{i}\right)$. Now if I knew that $\theta$ was measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$ then I would have that $\mathbb{E}(\theta | \mathcal{F}_{\infty}) = \theta$, but sadly I do not know that this is true...

I am pretty much stuck here. I do not know how to incorporate that the $Z_{i}$'s are i.i.d. with finite mean, or that $\theta$ is independent with finite mean.

I am honestly so bad at this stuff. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show that if $\theta=1_A$ for some measurable $A$ (measurable with respect to whatever sigma field $\theta$ is measurable with respect to), then $\mathbb{E}(\theta \mid \mathcal{F}_\infty)= \theta$ a.s.? Then you can argue the same holds if $\theta$ is a step function, an increasing limit of step functions, and finally any arbitrary function.

Comment: @kccu Yes this may be possible... since it seems to me it holds from Levy's 0-1 law. I will keep this in mind in case no one can find a more direct approach.

Comment: The "four step machine" of showing something works for indicator functions, then step functions, then limits of step functions, then arbitrary functions is a good tool to remember in probability. It's used quite often in proving results like this and often can't be avoided.

Comment: Indeed, the random variable $\theta$ is $\mathcal F_\infty$-measurable since, by the law of large numbers, $$\theta=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nY_i-E(Z_1)\qquad\text{almost surely}$$

Comment: @kccu Sorry but I have absolutely no idea what your pair of comments is referring to, which would be relevant to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: @Did You found a nice direct way to show $\theta$ is $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ measurable. I was just providing OP with a suggestion that sometimes works for problems like this. I don't actually know if it works to solve this problem or not.

Comment: @kccu "I don't actually know if it works to solve this problem or not." Huh? Something is seriously wrong here. The site is not made for random guesses (ineffective, in the present case) presented as hints to solve the problem asked. If you "don't actually know if (something) works to solve a problem" asked, at least make the fact perfectly clear in your comments.

Comment: @Did It's not uncommon for people to suggest lines of reasoning in the comments without knowing whether that will definitely solve OP's problem. And it is not a "random guess," as I said this method often works for problems similar to this one. I'll be sure to make it more clear I have not worked through the solution next time I offer a suggestion.

Comment: @kccu "It's not uncommon for people to suggest lines of reasoning in the comments without knowing whether that will definitely solve OP's problem" Really? Again, if guesses are presented as guesses, everything is allright.

Comment: @Did I am agreeing with you, and I said that I will make it more clear in the future when my hunches are hunches.

Comment: @Did Is there a nice way to show $E[Y_i]=\theta+E[Z_i]$ (to use in the SLLN)? I understand that for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, given that $\theta = a$, we have that $Y_i = Z_i + a$, and $E[Y_i] = E[Z_i] +a$, which in a way implies that $E[Y_i] = E[Z_i] + \theta$, but I feel like this is not very rigorous

Comment: @user428487 Actually, $E(Y_i)=E(\theta)+E(Z_i)$, not $E(Y_i)=\theta+E(Z_i)$, and this holds because $Y_i=\theta+Z_i$.

Comment: @Did but then doesn't SLLN give $E[\theta] = \lim_n \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i - E[Z_i]$, which doesn't show that $\theta$ is $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$ measurable?

Comment: Or, can we write $E[Y_i] = \lim_n \frac{1}{n} \sum_1^n Y_i = \lim_n \frac{1}{n} \sum_1^n \theta + \lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n Z_i = \theta + E[Z_i]$, since $\frac{1}{n} \sum_1^n \theta = \frac{1}{n} n \theta = \theta$? (the SLLN does not apply to $\theta$ because $\theta$ is not independent from $\theta$)

Comment: @user428487 Sorry but you have to start to be much more rigorous in what you write... To use the SLLN here, one first need a i.i.d. sequence, right? Hence the SLLN yields $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nZ_k\to E(Z)$. What does it say about the limit of $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nY_k-E(Z)$? QED.